# UWP: How to make sure async events are processed sequentially

Tags: c#, uwp, async-await, event-handling, thread-synchronization

I need to have an event handler to drag an element in my UWP project that performs awaited operations.

Therefore I need my event handler to be marked as async:

```
myElement.PointerMoved += OnPointerMoved;

public async void OnPointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
 await MyOperationAsync(); 
}
```

As a result, I found that the OnPointerMoved is called by the UWP framework even if the previous execution is not finished (which is foreseeable, given that you cannot await an async void method...).

I am looking for a solution to make sure that the code inside my event handler is called sequentially (i.e. the next execution of OnPointerMoved should happen after the previous one has actually finished).

Has anyone an elegant solution for that?

Comment: No, you can `await` an `async void`, just that the Framework calling your handler doesn’t.

Comment: Without seeing what `MyOperationAsync` actually does it’s hard to say.   Perhaps you should queue up all the operations and have your own thread/idle timer process them?

Comment: @MickyD i cannot use another thread because I need to access UiElements

Comment: Then use an idle dispatch timer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually an instance of the common [producer/consumer problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem) which has many solutions floating around the web.

However in your case the situation is a bit easier thanks to the fact that the event is always firing on the UI thread. So instead of running the operation immediately you can create a intermediary method that will queue the actions:

```
private bool _isProcessing = false;
private readonly Queue<PointerPoint> _operationQueue = new Queue<PointerPoint>();

private async Task EnqueueOperationAsync(PointerPoint point)
{
    //using the pointer point as argument of my operation in this example
    _operationQueue.Enqueue(point); 
    if (!_isProcessing)
    {
        _isProcessing = true;
        while (_operationQueue.Count != 0)
        {
            var argument = _operationQueue.Dequeue();
            await MyOperationAsync(argument);
        }
        _isProcessing = false;
    }
}

private async void UIElement_OnPointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await EnqueueOperationAsync(e.GetCurrentPoint(this));
}
```

If you make sure `EnqueueOperationAsync` is only called from the UI thread (which is the case if it is triggered by `OnPointerMoved`), this should work exactly as you require thanks to the fact, that there is only one UI thread and due to `await` automatically returning to the UI thread, the only place the `EnqueueOperationAsync` method can leave the UI thread is during `MyOperationAsync` execution, in which case `_isProcessing` must be `true`, so newly arriving operation will be enqueued only, and will be processed once the `MyOperationAsync` finishes and execution returns on the UI thread. Once there is nothing more to process, `while` terminates with `_operationQueue` being empty and `_isProcessing` is set to `false` - 
ready for another event to come.

I think this solution is sufficient in simple cases and should actually be safe unless someone calls `EnqueueOperationAsync` from a non-UI thread.

You could even check for this in the beginning of the method:

```
if (CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher.HasThreadAccess)
   throw new InvalidOperationException(
         "This method must be called from the UI thread");
```

**Note:** Altough the logic seems to be solid from my tests, I will rather check this with someone else as well :-)

Comment: Awesome :-) ! Thank you @StephenCleary